Differences in Presto SQL between Join via Where clause and Inner Join
I want to understand the differences in Presto SQL (result-wise and performance-wise) between the following 2 queries:
SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table2. field3
FROM
    table1
JOIN (or INNER JOIN)
    table2
ON
    table1.key1 = table2.key2

SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table2. field3
FROM
    table1, table2
WHERE
    table1.key1 = table2.key2

Want to understand the differences. I tried to run the 2 queries on some SQL engine, and it seems that at least these 2 queries are the same result-wise, but I still want to confirm it here.

The second version is not compliant with the ANSI SQL standard, has been outdated for 30+ years and is not generally considered good practise
